# getSingleResult() alters the count() Query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql, dao

My application uses Hibernate to connect to SQL Server. I recently changed my DAO function that retrieves the count from one of the tables from "return query.getResultList().get(0)" to "query.getSingleResult()". The sql count() query is supplied via namedQuery.

When I made this change, I noticed that the SQL generated by Hibernate has now changed from 
select count(test0_.TestId) as .....
to
select top 2 count(test0_.TestId) as...

Why would Hibernate translate to top 2 and not top 1 for getSingleResult()? 
Is there a way to turn off Hibernate modifying my count() query to use top 2 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSingleResult` throws an exception if there is not exactly one result. This is so it can check if there are more than one rows returned.

Answer (score 3):

> Why would Hibernate translate to top 2 and not top 1 for getSingleResult()?

Hibernate selects 2 entries in order to check if there's just one or more. If 2 are returned, it will throw an exception, since the result is not unique. If top 1 was used, Hibernate wouldn't be able to tell if there would be more.